# How is this enum property setter function called by spring boot request binding?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, enums, modelattribute

I have a enum for example:

```
public enum ENUM {

    E1("content1");

    private String data;

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }


    public void setData(String data) {
       this.data = data;
    }

}
```

And in spring boot request I have somewhat this structure

```
public class Request {
       ...
       ...
    private Param1 param1;
    public get...
    public set...
}


public class Param1 {
    private ENUM enum1;
    getter...setter
}
```

The request is get request parameter and `@ModelAttribute` is used.
Somehow `ENUM.E1.setData()` method is called automatically from request binder, which changes the data for it.

Now I know I can prevent this by removing setter method. But I can't figure out any request which can call the enum property setter method.
Any idea?

Comment: Why would you have a setter for a enum? It sort of defeats the purpose...

Comment: @Rcordoval agreed with you, it was just a mistake which we fixed later. But I was just curious about how the function is called somehow during request binding?